# AdMob instances limitation

Tags: android, ios, admob, interstitial

I am about to integrate AdMob in a mobile game. However I just want to make sure I don't break any AdMob rules. Speaking of interstitial banners I read that they are limited to five instances in an app/game.
Let's presume I have a mobile game with 20 levels. I need to know if showing interstitial banner on every level end counts for one instance only?

- Banner on every level end (no matter how many levels) counts for one instance
- Banner on game exit counts for second instance
- etc.

Do I understand the rules correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen any Admob documentation indicating that the number of interstitials shown in a game are limited. I don't believe that is the case. If you can show otherwise then include a link.

You seem to be confused about banners and interstitials. Banners are ads that take up a small amount of space across the width of your app (ie a banner). Interstitials are full screen ads.

Comment: "Implement interstitials upon your app’s launch, and natural breaks in the app experience, such as level completion, or after 10-20 interactions
Don’t exceed five interstitial ad units per user per session."